# React router, show 404 for non existent resource

Tags: react-router

I've just started to use react router and the experience turned out to be really nice. I normally do backend but I've joined forces with the front-end team to create our very first fully isomorphic app.

We have a simple router that looks like this

```
<Route path="/" {...props} component={AppContainer}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/home" />
  <Route path="/home" component={StaticContainer} require={loadStaticPage} />
  <Route path="/contact" component={StaticContainer} require={loadStaticPage} />
  <Route path="/:resource" component={ItemsContainer} require={loadItems} />
  <Route path="/:resource/:slug" component={ItemContainer} require={loadItem} />
</Route>
```

All the resources are dynamically fetched from the CMS (we are integrating this with an existing system) and our main issue is how to handle the not found cases.

In the old days I had a express application rendering everything and I did something that looked like this

```
router.get('/resource/:slug', (req, res, next) => {
  const resource = normallyNotSynchronousCall(req.params.slug);
  resource ? res.render('something', { resource }) : next();
});
```

So in case of a non existing resource I just called `next()` and it would eventually hit the last route that was just a catch all that rendered the 404 page.

I know that we can have the same idea in react router and add this as last route to catch everything.

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFoundContainer} />
```

But this will not work if the resources are dynamically fetched from the CMS. Is there a way to get an equivalent of `next()` in react router to skip the current route and start evaluating the next ones? So I can trigger some action depending on the response from the CMS and tell the router to skip the current route and start evaluating down the chain?

Probably it's an edge case, but I believe there are some uses for it.

Thanks for all the possible replies.

Comment: This might actually also be interesting for users using [tag:react-router-relay] where a resource might not exist in a database (e.g `/product/:id` where the route exists, but a non-existent `id` is given)

Comment: I have a similar issue with locale prefixes in url paths: A valid path would be `/de/some/resource` and we match with `path=':locale'`. But how can we show a 404 component when the visitor goes to `/some/resource`?